# git push heroku master error Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am new to heroku and I can't push my rails project.

I can successfully login to heroku, and I have keys

```
 Keys
 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...oPiDGoh0Gt root@Slava-System-Product-Name
```

but when I `git push heroku master` I receive

```
 Permission denied (publickey).
 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> A common key error is: Permission denied (publickey). You can fix this by using keys:add to notify Heroku of your new key.

```
heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

**UPDATE**, solution from the following blog [post](http://www.whatibroke.com/?p=284) worked.

1. Create a new public key

   ssh-keygen -t rsa
2. Upload to heroku

   heroku keys:add /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: I made this and upload SSH public key. But have the same error when try "git push heroku master"
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: What is the name of your public key? I have updated my answer.

Comment: I try "heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" any changes, same error. === s**************@gmail.com Keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...oPiDGoh0Gt root@Slava-System-Product-Name

Comment: in my root/.ssh/ i have files: id_rsa, id_rsa.pub,  known_hosts. Im not shure, but I use github keys from the same folder? Github works normal way.

Comment: Have you logged in? `heroku login`

Comment: Yes, Authentication successful.

Comment: Have you got more than 1 heroku account?

Comment: No, I have only 1 heroku acc, but i tried to create and delete keys many times.

Comment: I'd suggest you to clean all the previous keys, and start all over again. Not sure what might be causing your problem.

Comment: How heroku files from root/.ssh/ are related with Git keys? If i delete all of them could i have problems with git push?

Comment: You can then just add the keys to GitHub, https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I delete all keys from .ssh folder. Generate and add new keys but still have same error - Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: found solution here - http://www.whatibroke.com/?p=284

Comment: Glad you found the solution, I have updated my answer in case someone runs into the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Updated solution worked for me on Mac 10.8.4. Thanks!